# Images not being displayed in forwarded mails - php

Tags: php, html, email

I am using html email templates to send mail with image. and when i forward it to another mail then html template format is broken. I am using html templates in the following manner -

```
$message = file_get_contents('templates_folder/templatename.html');
```

mail($to, $from, $subject, $message);

and the image is defined in html template format is as follows -

```
<img src="urlofimage" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you build your headers  ?

Comment: i set like <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

You should build your headers for mail to make it view like a good template, else you might see only your code

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To:' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Admin<youremail@email.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Note :**

Also make sure that the image you include should be available to public and it should not be your localhost image.

You can also look this [example](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Comment: i have set header same as yours. and image is also displayed by public url. and images being displayed in mail. but when i forward this mail then only it is not being displayed.

Comment: Can you view the source of the forwarded email and check the image's path ?

Comment: Is the url changed, i guess your email vendor is wrapping the image's url !!

Comment: which email vendor is you using to forward ?? In outlook you should choose the option -> `Download Images` , In Gmail you should choose, `Show Images` like that.. You did it ?